# App running error when i try to run the app on mobile

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> BUILD FAILED in 12s PS D:\AbbasiBooks\android> npx react-native
> run-android error Failed to load configuration of your project. info
> Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

When I run the commend `npx react-native run-android` this error is appearing. Please tell me how solve it.

I also tried the `--verbose` but no change

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install` first.